# I am (likely) being accused of cheating by my professor, what do I do?

Tags: cheating

I took my final last Wednesday (it’s Monday) and on Friday I received an email from my professor asking to meet to discuss my performance on the final. I got a little stressed but was more worried about if I failed the exam and have to retake the course. There was one other person I knew that got this email and he had the meeting today. The professor basically just said that there is proof of him cheating and said that he was on Moodle looking at the other tests while taking the final exam. This person said he did not and the professor just said he will have to fill out a form saying he did or did not and has to attend a hearing about it.

I have my meeting with the professor tomorrow and am EXTREMELY worried now. Being upfront, I did not cheat, I had Moodle open on my laptop in a minimized window but was not actively looking at it. I also have a full ride that would definitely disappear if I had something like this. What do I do?

PS: the professor already said to my friend that even if Moodle was open on a minimized window, the site wouldn’t give the report of accessing materials during the final exam.

Edit: grammar in PS section.

Comment: *it wouldn’t give that report* --- What does the second "it" refer to? professor? friend? Moodle? None of these make sense. Also, "give that report" seems misworded -- if your professor isn't giving the report, then what is the concern?

Comment: What is the full ride?

Comment: @user111388 "Full ride" refers to a scholarship covering all education cost including tuition and (sometimes) room and board.

Comment: @Dave L Renfro my apologies, I meant to say Moodle wouldn’t give the report of accessing materials during the exam.

Comment: Then perhaps you mean something like this? "The professor told my friend that if Moodle was open, but on a minimized window, then the evidence the professor is basing the claim on would not exist." (The original use of "even" seems misplaced, since one would expect a condition more likely to set off a cheating alarm to follow "even", not a condition that seems less likely of setting off a cheating alarm.)

Comment: Would access to an open Moodle give you an advantage in the exam?

Comment: "What should I do" is not a question. Also a duplicate of many other "accused by AI of cheating during online exam" questions.

Comment: Were there instructions to have certain software or all software except XYZ closed during the exam? If so, there might not be much defense to having software open against the instructions, even if this is a relatively poor way of detecting cheating. Much like for athletes who test positive for diuretics.

Answer (score 3):

First, don't assume that the concerns about one person are necessarily the same as concerns about another. It may just be coincidence.

Second, the history is what it is. If there is some "evidence" that you did something wrong you will just have to explain it as best you can and live with the consequences.

It may well be that the monitoring system gets a report of open windows/apps but can't distinguish what is visible to the user from what is not.

Explain your actions. I suggest honestly. If you didn't cheat, then insist on that and don't agree to "lesser penalties" if you admit to something you didn't do.

---

Also note that statements about what automated systems do or don't do can be checked experimentally and/or by contacting the vendor.

Comment: 'note that statements about what automated systems do or don't do can be checked experimentally'  Caution: at least one automated system in this field of endeavour (Turnitin) has a "no reverse engineering" clause in its terms of use.

Comment: This is a good answer. And next time don't leave your moodle window open during an exam (even minimized). It is like having a cheat sheet on your desk during the exam and saying: "but I did not look at it, honestly!"

Comment: @DanielHatton, clauses like that can be overcome in a court of law should OP choose to carry it that far. The software is effectively a witness against them which could be made to show how it came to focus on them. This would be an expensive endeavor.

Comment: @DanielHatton. software used for grading and, especially sanctioning students, needs to be transparent in its operation. If it isn't then it shouldn't be used. But testing the validity of a system doesn't necessarily imply reverse engineering.

Comment: 'software used for... sanctioning students needs to be transparent in its operation. If it isn't then it shouldn't be used'  Agreed, and IMO the "no reverse engineering" clause does somewhat get in the way of that transparency.  There's also a "no derivative works" clause which forces what I believe to be an undesirable level of obfuscation on formal plagiarism complaints in which a Turnitin report is a major exhibit in evidence.  (I'm singling out Turnitin because it's the only automated anti-cheating tool with which I'm familiar, but I'd imagine there are others with similar problems.)

Comment: @DanielHatton, see this [Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/technology/2020/11/12/test-monitoring-student-revolt/) article.

Comment: Ironically, the Washington Post website won't let me proceed to the article unless I tick a box agreeing to "no reverse engineering" and "no derivative works" clauses, _and_ to the use of cookies for cross-site analytics and targeted advertising.  Yes, I know I could tick the box dishonestly then block the cookies anyway, but...

Comment: @DanielHatton, yes, sadly, their model is intended for subscribers only. The article was widely discussed elsewhere, so perhaps you can find a review of it that is open. I finally gave in and subscribed since their news is fairly comprehensive.

Comment: @DanielHatton and Buffy, many times you can find _Washington Post_ in electronic form through your library (public or academic). As this is academia.SE, probably your institution has access through ProQuest or EBSCO or Gale.